# jstree rebuild after appending ul or li from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jstree

How do we rebuid jstree if I add ul/li from ajax? because i initiate
the js tree using the ul li html.

for example I need to add an li  clickme.
on the first node. I ideally i thougt i was just append() function. but doesnt seem to rebuild the jstree.

```
<div id="tree_1">
    <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{ "opened" : true, "type" : "root" }'> Global - DemoFLow1
            <ul>
                <li data-jstree='{ "opened" : true }' li_id="1"> Default paths
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="tree-name">Path 1</span>
                            <span class="tree-value">125 (20.00%)</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="tree-name">Path 2</span>
                            <span class="tree-value">125 (20.00%)</span>
                        </li>
                        <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "btn" }'><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs grey-mint"> Add new path </button> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-jstree='{ "opened" : true }' li_id="2"> Rule 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="tree-name">Path 1</span>
                            <span class="tree-value">125 (20.00%)</span>
                        </li>
                        <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "btn" }'><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs grey-mint"> Add new path </button> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "btn" }'><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs grey-mint"> Add new rule </button></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


var tree = $('#tree_1').jstree({
                "core" : {
                    "themes" : {
                        "responsive": false
                    }            
                },
                "types" : {
                    "default" : {
                        "icon" : "fa fa-circle-o"
                    },
                    "path" : {
                        "icon" : "fa fa-circle-o"
                    },
                    "root" : {
                        "icon" : "fa fa-circle"
                    },
                    "btn" : {
                        "icon" : "fa fa-plus"
                    }
                },
                "plugins": ["types"]
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would use in your ajax callback code like below.

This adds a new node to the tree root:

```
$('#tree_1').jstree().create_node( '#',  "New node");
```

To add some attribute values you would use:

```
$('#tree_1').jstree().create_node( '#',  { "id": "newid", "name": "New node", "type" : "btn", "li_attr": { "attr1": "value of attr1", "attr2": "value of attr2"}})
```

To add a new node to some node other than root you will need to replace `#` with that node id.

The exact usage will depend on what you get as an ajax response from server.

Also check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/6npnLkt0/)

Comment: how do i add custom attributes to the ul or li? cause as you see i had  li_id="1" as a sample, but there are other ones aswell

Comment: I updated the answer. To do that you will need to pass some extra parameters to create method. Some special attributes you can pass through `li_attr` key, while values for `id`, `name` and `type` you would pass with the same keys. And you don't need to do anything special for `ul`, because jsTree will build them automatically.